# CakePHP HasOne relationship - Limit options to add

Tags: cakephp-1.3

Maybe I do not understand the associative relationships in CakePHP correctly, here is where my mental model is right now:

a User HasOne Profile and a Profile BelongsTo a User in my cakeApp.

Nevertheless from my User account I can add multiple profiles and Cake lets it all happen
. Does this mean that the HasOne association does not limit the number of Profiles? Do I need to write some code to prevent a user to add more than 1 Profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations are correct.  It might be better if you just don't allow them to "add" a profile at all - instead, create it [afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1053/afterSave) in the model.  This is triggered immediately after saving a user the first time.

Then, you don't have to worry about it at all - if you have a user in the database, they're guaranteed to have an associated profile.

You can also set that it's [[dependent]](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1041/hasOne) on the user, so if/when a user gets deleted, CakePHP will handle the deleting of the profile automatically.

Minor note - it should be `belongsTo` and `hasOne` (not capitalized).

([this page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1041/hasOne) specifies your exact associations - and it's right in the CakePHP book! :)

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will dive into the afterSave().